# Entity Framework 4 - Erro Migrations: O tipo ... não é definido no namespace <namespace>.Map (Alias=Self)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent-api

Estou com um problema nos mapeamentos da minha aplicação.

**[EDITADO]**

Segue a Classe DataContext Completa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Setor.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Perfil.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Telefone.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Endereco.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Email.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Funcionario.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Categoria.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Finalizacao.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Comentario.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Chamado.Models;

namespace SisprodIT2.Map
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<SetorModel> Setores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PerfilModel> Perfis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TelefoneModel> Telefones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EnderecoModel> Enderecos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmailModel> Emails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FuncionarioModel> Funcionarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CategoriaModel> Categorias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FinalizacaoModel> Finalizacoes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ComentarioModel> Comentarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChamadoModel> Chamados { get; set; }

        protected override void  OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SetorMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PerfilMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TelefoneMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EnderecoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmailMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FuncionarioMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoriaMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FinalizacaoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ComentarioMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChamadoMap());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Segue a classe FuncionarioModel completa:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Setor.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Email.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Perfil.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Endereco.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Telefone.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Chamado.Models;

namespace SisprodIT2.Areas.Funcionario.Models
{
    public class FuncionarioModel : BaseCadastro
    {
        public int FuncionarioModelId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="CPF")]
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RG")]
        public string RG { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Altura")]
        public float Altura { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string Senha { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Perfil")]
        public int PerfilModelId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Setor")]
        public int SetorModelId { get; set; }

        public virtual SetorModel Setor { get; set; }
        public virtual PerfilModel Perfil { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmailModel> EmailLista { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EnderecoModel> EnderecoLista { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TelefoneModel> TelefoneLista { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ChamadoModel> ChamadoLista { get; set; }

        public FuncionarioModel()
        {
            TelefoneLista = new List<TelefoneModel>();
            EnderecoLista = new List<EnderecoModel>();
            EmailLista = new List<EmailModel>();
            ChamadoLista = new List<ChamadoModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Segue a classe ChamadoModel completa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Funcionario.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Categoria.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Comentario.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Finalizacao.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SisprodIT2.Areas.Chamado.Models
{
    public class ChamadoModel : BaseCadastro
    {
        [Display(Name="ID")]
        public int ChamadoModelId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Título")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Revisão")]
        public int Revisao { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descrição do Problema")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Categoria")]
        public int CategoriaModelId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Criador do Chamado")]
        public int FuncionarioCriadorId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Atribuido a")]
        public int FuncionarioResponsavelId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cod Finalização")]
        public int FinalizacaoModelId { get; set; }

        public virtual FuncionarioModel FuncionarioCriador { get; set; }
        public virtual FuncionarioModel FuncionarioResponsavel { get; set; }
        public virtual CategoriaModel Categoria { get; set; }
        public virtual FinalizacaoModel Finalizacao { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ComentarioModel> ComentarioLista { get; set; }

        public ChamadoModel()
        {
            ComentarioLista = new List<ComentarioModel>();
            FuncionarioCriador = new FuncionarioModel();
            FuncionarioResponsavel = new FuncionarioModel();
            Finalizacao = new FinalizacaoModel();
            Categoria = new CategoriaModel();
        }
    }
}
```

O mapeamento FuncionarioMap:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Funcionario.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Chamado.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SisprodIT2.Map
{
    public class FuncionarioMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FuncionarioModel>
    {
        public FuncionarioMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.FuncionarioModelId);

            Property(x => x.FuncionarioModelId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.Nome).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.CPF).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.RG).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.Nascimento).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.Altura).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.Usuario).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Senha).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.PerfilModelId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.SetorModelId).IsRequired();

            Property(x => x.DataCadastro).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.DataAtualizacao).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.FuncionarioAtualizadorId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Ativo).IsRequired();


            HasRequired(x => x.Setor)
                .WithMany(y => y.FuncionarioLista)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.SetorModelId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasRequired(x => x.Perfil)
                .WithMany(y => y.FuncionarioLista)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.PerfilModelId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            ToTable("Funcionario");
        }
    }
}
```

O mapeamento ChamadoMap:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Chamado.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Funcionario.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Categoria.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Areas.Finalizacao.Models;
using SisprodIT2.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SisprodIT2.Map
{
    public class ChamadoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChamadoModel>
    {
        public ChamadoMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.ChamadoModelId);

            Property(x => x.ChamadoModelId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Titulo).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Revisao).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Status).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Descricao).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.CategoriaModelId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.FuncionarioCriadorId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavelId).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.FinalizacaoModelId).IsOptional();

            Property(x => x.DataCadastro).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.DataAtualizacao).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.FuncionarioAtualizadorId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Ativo).IsRequired();

            HasRequired(x => x.FuncionarioCriador)
                .WithMany(x => x.ChamadoLista)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FuncionarioCriadorId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasOptional(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavel)
                .WithMany(x => x.ChamadoLista)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavelId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasRequired(x => x.Categoria)
                .WithMany(y => y.ChamadoLista)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoriaModelId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasOptional(x => x.Finalizacao)
                .WithMany(y => y.ChamadoLista)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FinalizacaoModelId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            ToTable("Chamado");


        }
    }
}
```

Segue o erro completo abaixo:

```
PM> Add-Migration AlteracoesMapeamentos
System.Data.MetadataException: O esquema especificado não é válido. Erros: 
(120,6) : erro 0040: O tipo ChamadoModel_FuncionarioCriador não é definido no namespace SisprodIT2.Map (Alias=Self).
   em System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
   em System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   em System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   em System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ToEdmItemCollection(EdmModel model)
   em System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Db.Mapping.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToMetadataWorkspace(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace..ctor(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel..ctor(DbModel model)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
O esquema especificado não é válido. Erros: 
(120,6) : erro 0040: O tipo ChamadoModel_FuncionarioCriador não é definido no namespace SisprodIT2.Map (Alias=Self).
PM>
```

Onde estou errando?

Estou usando Entity Framework 4 com Fluent API.

Comment: vc adicionou o mapeamento FuncionarioModel no contexto ?

Comment: O problema está na separação de Models. Aparentemente, a Fluent API considera que o mapeamento e os *Models* estão no mesmo diretório. Há algum motivo específico para esta separação?

Comment: Se você estiver falando da separação do Model Funcionario em FuncionarioCriador e FuncionarioResponsavel, preciso deles para definir quem criou o chamado e quem irá ser o responsável por atender o chamado...

Comment: Sim, mas qual a necessidade de separar por *namespaces*? Além disso, qual seria o impeditivo de atualizar o Entity Framework?

Comment: Eu tinha lido errado a sua pergunta. 

Então, estou usando Areas do ASP.NET MVC por questões de organização mesmo. Os mapeamentos estão na Raiz por questão de organização também. 

Até então, os mapeamentos estavam funcionando sem problema nesta estrutura. Só começou a ocorrer o erro depois que eu adicionei o mapeamento Chamado.Map com os FuncionarioCriador e FuncionarioResponsavel. Antes estava somente Funcionario e funcionou 100%.

Sobre o Entity Framework, estou usando o Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @FBatista, obrigado por responder. Adicionei sim, conforme você pode ver no texto editado, mas o problema persiste. Alguma ideia?

Comment: A sua classe dbcontext, coloca ela tbm, toda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a resposta!

Segundo esta [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081256/entity-framework-code-first-union-of-the-two-fields-into-one-collection), não é possivel ter duas propriedades navegacionais numa mesma propriedade simples.

Com isto, na classe FuncionarioModel, alterei o código:

```cs
public ICollection<ChamadoModel> ChamadoLista { get; set; }
```

para:

```cs
public ICollection<ChamadoModel> ChamadoListaCriador { get; set; }
public ICollection<ChamadoModel> ChamadoListaResponsavel { get; set; }
```

e instanciei estas Collections no construtor:

```cs
public FuncionarioModel()
    {
        TelefoneLista = new List<TelefoneModel>();
        EnderecoLista = new List<EnderecoModel>();
        EmailLista = new List<EmailModel>();
        ChamadoListaCriador = new List<ChamadoModel>();
        ChamadoListaResponsavel = new List<ChamadoModel>();
    }
```

Na classe Chamado.Map, alterei os códigos:

```cs
HasRequired(x => x.FuncionarioCriador)
            .WithMany(x => x.ChamadoLista)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FuncionarioCriadorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

HasOptional(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavel)
            .WithMany(x => x.ChamadoLista)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavelId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Para:

```cs
HasRequired(x => x.FuncionarioCriador)
            .WithMany(x => x.ChamadoListaCriador)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FuncionarioCriadorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

HasOptional(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavel)
            .WithMany(x => x.ChamadoListaResponsavel)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FuncionarioResponsavelId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

E agora o comando Add-Migration funcionou 100%.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Boa! Já estou há uns anos com EF code first, e essa eu não tinha visto ainda, mais uma pro repertório!

Answer (score 1):

No construtor da classe ChamadoModel  Inicializa os demais

```
 public ChamadoModel()
    {
        ComentarioLista = new List<ComentarioModel>();
FuncionarioCriador  = new FuncionarioModel ();
FuncionarioResponsavel  = new FuncionarioModel ();
Categoria  = new CategoriaModel();
Finalizacao = new FinalizacaoModel();

    }
```

Comment: Pode ser também que esteja dando conflito nesse tipo de relacionamento

public virtual FuncionarioModel FuncionarioCriador { get; set; }public virtual FuncionarioModel FuncionarioResponsavel { get; set; }

Comment: inicializei os demais, conforme você orientou, mas o problema ainda persiste.

Comment: Warleson Reis, o erro começou a ocorrer justamente quando alterei o mapeamento "Chamado.Map" com os "FuncionarioCriador" e "FuncionarioResponsavel". Antes estava somente "Funcionario" e funcionou 100%.

Answer (score 1):

A classe do mapeamento está em outro *namespace* que não o *namespace* dos *Models*.

Ao definir um mapeamento novo, certifique-se de que esteja usando as dependências necessárias.

```
using SisprodIT2.Models;
```

Comment: Adicionei as dependências e o erro permanece.

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar os arquivos completos, com dependências e *namespaces*?